# downloaded pdf file is in wrong format

Tags: javascript, axios

I'm implementing the javascript code that fetch the pdf file and download 
when user click on the button. but when i download pdf file. It seems to be 
in the wrong format.

Here my code

```
 fetchPdfDownload = (fileName) => {
    return axios.get(`/api/pdf`, {
      params: {
        'file': fileName,
      },
    })
  }
async onClick () {
    try {
      let response = await this.fetchPdfDownload(this.props.symbol)

      const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data], {type: "application/pdf; encoding=UTF-8"}));
      const link = document.createElement('a')
      link.href = url
      link.setAttribute('download', 'file.pdf')
      document.body.appendChild(link)
      link.click()
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
  }
```

I try to find the method in here. I try to change the responseType to 'blob' and 'arraybuffer' but it seems to have no effect. The pdf seems to
have the same page as the server pdf but with no content.

Here are example of header

```
 content-disposition: attachment; filename=example.pdf; filename*=UTF-8''example.pdf 
 content-length: 592283 
 content-type: application/pdf 
 date: Thu, 30 Aug 2018 17:43:06 GMT 
 server: Kestrel 
 x-powered-by: ASP.NET
```

Anyone have any idea what going on.

Comment: Why not just construct the `<a>` with the address that you are going to pass to axios directly?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you aren't just constructing the  with the address that you are going to pass to axios directly, but I think that axios may be returning your PDF in the wrong format which makes `Blob()` misbehave.

I don't know how to get axios to turn stuff into `Buffer`s, but I do know how to do it with fetch.  Consider the following:

```js
async function loadPDF(fileName) {
    const res = await fetch(`/api/pdf?file=${fileName}`);
    const buff = await res.blob();
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(buff);
    const link = document.createElement("a");
    link.href = url;
    link.setAttribute("download", "file.pdf");
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
}
```

Using axios this worked with a PDF that I tried:

```js
async function loadPDF(fileName) {
    const blob = await axios.get(`/api/pdf?file=${fileName}`, {
        responseType: "blob"
    });
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob.data);
    const link = document.createElement("a");
    link.href = url;
    link.setAttribute("download", "file.pdf");
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
}
```